# "Variable shadowed" warning in lambda (when not captured)

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, compiler-warnings

Let's consider this code:

```cpp
int main()
{
    int a = 1;

    auto f1 = [a]() {
        int a = 10;
        return a;
    };

    auto f2 = []() {
        int a = 100;
        return a;
    };

    return a + f1() + f2();
}
```

When using flag `-Wshadow` with gcc (tested on 10.2), we get these warnings:

```
<source>:26:13: warning: declaration of 'a' shadows a lambda capture [-Wshadow]
    6 |         int a = 10;

<source>:21:13: warning: declaration of 'a' shadows a previous local [-Wshadow]
   11 |         int a = 100;
```

I understand the first case, where we explicitly capture `a`, and thus are shadowing the original local. However, the second case is interesting, because if we remove declaration `int a = 100;` we get a compile error (= `error: 'a' is not captured: return a;`). Doesn't that "prove" that the declaration is not in the same scope as the original local, and thus we are not actually shadowing anything? Hence my question, whether the warning (for the second case) is indeed valid, or whether gcc is being a bit too strict here?

Comment: What compiler error do you get when you omit the `int a = 100;` line?

Comment: I think that's a compiler bug - [clang does not report it](https://wandbox.org/permlink/26quYoNLFAz0epnt).

Comment: @PaulSanders Clang does report a warning for `f2` if you provide the `-Wshadow-all` option though.

Comment: @heapunderrun Sorry, my bad.  When I switched from gcc to clang, Wandbox cleared the compiler options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct, lambda `a` doesn't shadow `main::a` because `main::a` isn't captured in the lambda, thus is not on scope there.

However I think about what the purpose of the shadow warning is: to avoid programmer confusion. If a long body of code if the programmer sees the outer declaration, but doesn't see the inner declaration he or she may incorrectly assume that a use of the inner variable refers to the outer variable. And this possible confusion still applies here, even if the variable doesn't tehnically shadow the outer one.

I don't know if this is the intention of the warning or if it is a bug. Or even if that is a compelling enough reason to have a warning even a differently worded one. Shadow warning are problematic anyways. You can find a lot of discussions and bug reports about shadow warning that even if tehnically correct are considered harmful.

Comment: As for "You can find a lot of discussions and bug reports about shadow warning that even if technically correct are considered harmful", do you mind elaborating?

Answer (score 5):

The name does indeed being shadowed. you can still access it with `decltype` for example.

```cpp
int main()
{
    int a = 1;

    auto f1 = []() {
        return decltype(a){}; // int{}
    };

    auto f2 = []() {
        auto a = nullptr;
        return decltype(a){}; // nullptr_t{}
    };

    return a + f1() + f2();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/5b6Ybf136

Comment: +1 This is a better explanation of the consistency of the behaviour than "the dev might get confused," even if the latter is true as well.

Answer (score 2):

> Doesn't that "prove" that the declaration is not in the same scope as the original local, and thus we are not actually shadowing anything?

Exactly. The outer `a` is not in scope. Your declaration in the second example doesn't shadow anything.

> Hence my question, whether the warning (for the second case) is indeed valid, or whether gcc is being a bit too strict here?

There's nothing in that second warning worth paying attention to other than that the false shadowing would probably not have happened had you named your variables something more expressive than `a`.

Comment: gcc is also inconsistent and doesn't warn if you make it [a little functor](https://godbolt.org/z/9G1PG1) instead of a lambda